# How to use the variable "rev" outside the while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

After running the code shown below, I receive the following error:

```
rev cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I have tried to declare the variable outside the while loop, but it only leads to more errors. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalindromeProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number to check if palindrome");
        int number = num.nextInt();
        int temp=number;
        while(temp!=0) {
         int rem=temp%10;
         int rev=(rev*10)+rem;
            temp=temp/10;
        }
        if(rev==number){
            System.out.println("Number provided is palindrome");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Number provided is not palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors did declaring it outside the loop lead to? The error you are currently seeing is normal, because the variable goes out of scope outside the loop, and the solution is to declare and initialize it out of the loop.

Comment: You'd have to declare and initialise it before the loop.

Comment: You use temp variable the same way as you want to use rev. Just try to repeat.

Comment: Shouldn't you be testing `if (temp==number)` , not `rev`?

Comment: @TomT `temp` is always zero after the loop.

Comment: I followed JustAnotherDeveloper and khelwood's advice and it worked, Thank you.

Comment: Make your own answer. That will get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the **rev** cannot be resolved to a variable is because you are performing operations with it outside of its scope.

You created the integer **rev** in the while loop. In this case, you can only make modifications in the loop.

If you want to perform operations on **rev**, you have to initialize it outside of the loop.

It should look like the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalindromeProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number to check if palindrome");
        int number = num.nextInt();
        int temp=number;
        int rev=0;
        while(temp!=0) {
         int rem=temp%10;
         rev=(rev*10)+rem;
            temp=temp/10;
        }
        if(rev==number){
            System.out.println("Number provided is palindrome");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Number provided is not palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```